# Facebook Graph Api Image CDN connection timeout

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, vps

I have a few customers that want some integration between their website and their facebook page.
One wanted a feed integration to their website. When calling graph api, i ask for these fields: "message,id,full_picture".

The problem i have is that when developing locally using laragon, it shows the full_image correctly.
The field is just returning a url for Facebooks cdn, that points to the image from that post.

But when i deploy it to my Hostinger VPS server in Lithuania with CyberPanel installed, The images does not load. I noticed the differences in the Facebook CDN url as you can see here:

Locally: "https://scontent.faar2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/376685499_686144143534506_3964541178879225900_n.jpg?stp=cp1_dst-jpg_p720x720&_nc_cat=106&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=5614bc&_nc_ohc=LAMJl62qcq4AX_hJ_Mp&_nc_ht=scontent.faar2-1.fna&edm=AKK4YLsEAAAA&oh=00_AfDbKybfzrKctEaDdmzMH7pDwV_5LikiTTW_DE9KIzhcag&oe=650B40E2"

Hosted: "https://scontent.fvno8-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/376685499_686144143534506_3964541178879225900_n.jpg?stp=cp1_dst-jpg_p720x720&_nc_cat=106&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=5614bc&_nc_ohc=LAMJl62qcq4AX9ogYu8&_nc_ht=scontent.fvno8-1.fna&edm=AKK4YLsEAAAA&oh=00_AfAUVwAKRw0unga4xsRGXSl5KSOXYz4x5JQV38Yps7qLEg&oe=650B40E2"

The hosted url simple doesn't load as it times out the connection.

I tried doing the exact same code but on my bluehost shared hosting, and it worked just fine. I really need someones help on this.

What do i do?

Thanks,

- Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i ended up just moving the server to France and that fixed it...